# Instance member 'query' cannot be used on type 'GeoFire'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

how can I get the Value of this GeoFire?

Error Message: Instance member 'query' cannot be used on type 'GeoFire'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

```
 let center = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
                
                let circleQuery = GeoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 20);
                
                circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered) { (key, location,snapshot) in
                              // parse the snapshot for your result.
                               print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
                           }
```

Original Code: [How to query nearest users in Firebase with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091994/how-to-query-nearest-users-in-firebase-with-swift)

Comment: Check the original code: `let geofireRef = /* ... */; let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef); geoFire.query(/*...*/)`

Comment: I made this and now there are not any errors but the App is crashing....

Comment: because of empty array...(Thread 1: "*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray")

Comment: I don' see any array in your code; you'll have to provide more to show the exact line where it is crashing.

Comment: var geofire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: querySnapshot!.documents[0].get("koordinaten") as! DatabaseReference)

Comment: Well, `querySnapshot!.documents` seems to be an empty array, so you cannot access element 0 from it. Btw, you should avoid those crashes by using `if let` or at least _optional chaining_

Comment: Can you give me an example? If (querySnapshot!.documents == null) ??

Comment: But than it is only skipped or? So the App does not crash but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

From the question you linked, and the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#swift-5), it seems the method is called

```
geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 20);
```

Also note that both locations show that you need to initialize an instance of `GeoFire`. You can't just call query methods on the class.

Comment: queryAtLocation(_:withRadius:)' has been renamed to 'query(at:withRadius:)'

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the above comments of me:

- You need to create an instance of GeoFire to access the query methods.
- To create that instance, you need to connect it to a Firebase database first (`firebaseRef` needs to point anywhere into the database).

Hence:

```
let geofireRef = Database.database().reference()
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
```

Then, to query that instance, simply use it:

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
                
let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 20);
```

and then go on to observe the `circleQuery`

Comment: output is: "<GFCircleQuery: 0x600002cec690>
<GFCircleQuery: 0x600002cec690>"

Comment: I don't understand you comments. First, _what_ output do you  mean? The `print()` will output something like `Key ...`. Then, what is the second device?

Comment: Ok I want to see all people around my own location. I already implemented the location manager with didUpdate location and wrote it to the firebase database. Now I want to fetch in a new function the users which are in my zone....

Comment: OK, but that's a completly different question. You should accept this and create a new one, and provide more code / sample data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062480/get-all-users-in-your-zone-with-geofire-4-firebase-7-at-swift-5

Comment: There is the new topic with all details I give